# onClick function causes refresh on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've come across a very bizzare behavior on my Chrome. The following code causes the page to be refreshed on Chrome when I click on the add button which is not what I want it to do:

```
function addSpamAddr() 
{
    var email = prompt("Add Spam Address","");
    if (email == null || email == "")
        return false;

    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    if (regex.test(email) == false) {
        alert("You must enter a valid E-Mail address");
        return false;
    }


    var listBox = document.getElementById('spamList');
    for (var x = 0; x < listBox.options.length; x++) {
        if (listBox.options[x].value == email || listBox.options[x].text == email) {
            alert("Already blocked address");
            return false;
        }
    }

    var selectBoxOption = document.createElement("option");
    selectBoxOption.value = email;
    selectBoxOption.text = email;
    listBox.add(selectBoxOption);

    return false;
}


...
<button style="margin-right: 20px;width:60px" onclick="addSpamAddr()">Add</button>
```

The code works perfectly fine on Internet Explorer. I've created a minimal example to further investigate the issue:

```
function addSpamAddr()
{
   return false;
}
...
<button style="margin-right: 20px;width:60px" onclick="addSpamAddr()">Add</button>
```

Still causes refresh on Chrome.

How can I prevent the refresh?

Edit: After I added the return statement inside the onclick event, the page no longer refreshes on the minimal example I created.

```
<button style="margin-right: 20px;width:60px" onclick="return addSpamAddr()">Add</button>
```

However, the page would still refresh if I apply my original code. Particularly, this part causes it:

```
    var listBox = document.getElementById('spamList');
    var exists = false;
    for (var x = 0; x < listBox.options.length; x++) {
        if (listBox.options[x].value == email || listBox.options[x].text == email) {
            alert("Already blocked address");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: is the button element within a form?

Comment: oh ok, take a look at [this chrome thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Z3MD5Od3oQM), it can be a little weird with buttons and forms. A way to stop this would be to add the event arg to `addSpamAddr` (e.g. `addSpamAddr(e){...}`) and then call `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form submitting. Not sure if that solves exactly yr problem but I remembered there are some interesting corner cases for chrome in this situation.

Comment: have you tried to specify the type of the button like this `<button type="button" ... >Add</button>`? every browser use a different default button type so it's a good idea to specify it  ...

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano Wow, adding the type prevents the page refresh now but now I've got a different problem: The code does not work as intended. Again, this behavior is seen only on chrome..

Comment: Never mind, everything solved! Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

write like this

```
function addSpamAddr()
{
   return false;
}
...
<button style="margin-right: 20px;width:60px" onclick="return addSpamAddr()">Add</button>
```

you for got to write `"return addSpamAddr()"` in your html cod which is updated by me

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That solved a portion of my issue but the refreshing part still does not go away if I apply the original code. If you could take a look at the edited portion, I'd appreciate it